# Ebooks on the iPad

Tags: adobe-indesign, pdf, ipad

Is there a way to get full functionality of an interactive pdf , created in InDesign, on the iPad? The interactive pdf file loses various functionality when opened on a iPad.

Comment: This is too broad as there could be several possibilities  of "functionality".  If you want interactive content you should build an app.

Comment: Indesign can save as epub.... so....

Answer (score 0):

Not directly from InDesign.

You'll have to recreate some of your desired functionality inside Apple's iBooks Author, and yet others in JavaScript for iBooks Author... and some you'll have to give up on.

Adobe and Apple don't get along, nor see eye to eye. This started long before the spat over Flash.

PDF was one of the victims, as was SVG, and Quicktime's greater (and completely) forgotten potential.